# Checkbox itemrenderer displaying the wrong selected value in datagrid

Tags: datagrid, checkbox, flash-builder, itemrenderer

I have a checkbox as itemRenderer in my datagrid. I am setting the selected value from a column from my database table. The value of the variable is "true", but my checkbox is selected although I am setting its selected property to the datafield which is true.

My Code is as follows:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myGD" fontSize="9" enabled="true" x="20" y="20" width="217" height="60">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="selected" width="20" headerText="isDefault" dataField="IS_DEFAULT">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:CheckBox selected="{Boolean(data['IS_DEFAULT'])}" horizontalCenter="0"/>
                    </mx:HBox>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Can someone help me understand what is going wrong here?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item renderer should look like this.
Actually, my true and false value was being sent as String.
Hence, both were being evaluated to true.

```
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
       <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="left">
           <s:CheckBox selected="{data.MY_FIELD == 'false' ? false : true}" horizontalCenter="0"/>
       </mx:HBox>
    </fx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```